# ColdFusion - Date and Time formatting is rounding up 5 minutes

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, mura

I have the following date string:

```
2017-05-02 08:00:00.0
```

When I apply datetimeformat() like:

```
 #datetimeformat(item.getValue('releasedate'), 'h:mm a')#
```

It is rounding up by 5 minutes and outputting: 8:05 AM. In the code above, 'releasedate' is the string that is being passed in.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Nobody is rounding anything here; you are outputting the _month_ here instead of the minutes. https://cfdocs.org/datetimeformat

Comment: @CBroe you should add that as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Nobody is rounding anything.** You are outputting the *month* here instead of the minutes, and the month happens to be May, so that is `05` with leading zero.

https://cfdocs.org/datetimeformat:

> `mm`: Month as digits; leading zero for single-digit months.

Minutes are not `mm` here, but

> `nn`: minutes; a leading zero for single-digit minutes

Comment: @JesseEarley - You were probably thinking of timeFormat(), which does allow both `m` and `n` for "hour". Though better to stick with `n`, less ambiguous.

Comment: Date masking is a huge pet peeve of mine. It can be somewhat inconsistent in what comes out the back end. Letter case can matter, as you just encountered. Pay special attention if you are using ColdFusion with something like moment.js. For some real fun, try the difference between 'YYYY' and 'yyyy'. Then try it for December 29th.

Comment: @Shawn - It just follows the [java rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  Personally I find them more comprehensible (and flexible :) .. Plus, unlike the CF docs, the javadocs have *lots* of examples for easy look-up. Wish they'd just used the complete java's rules from the get-go.

Comment: @Leigh Yes. And I do find the Java masking to be very thorough. But I absolutely hate when masking treats upper and lower cased characters the same. I've had issues with using moment.js in a ColdFusion application, taking the moment mask of "MM/DD/YYYY" and just reusing it in a CFC. The "D" will show up pretty easily, but "Y" only shows up on about 3 days a year. It's not fun to debug why your date just became "12/29/2018". You have to be very cognizant when using date masks and multiple languages.

Comment: @Shawn - But "Y" do you have a problem with that? (Sorry, could not resist ;-).  I hear ya' though.  Oh the many joys of switching between languages ...

Comment: @Leigh Week Year (Y) vs Calendar Year (y) < something I never knew I never wanted to have to learn about. In moment, you'd use "MM/DD/YYYY" but in CF (depending on the date or datetime function), you'd use "MM/dd/yyyy". Just copying the mask to getDate() in CF displays as expected, but in getDateTime() returns something else. getDate() doesn't care about time and doesn't use Java's SimpleDateFormat, but getDateTime() does. :-S Can't remember the other functions affected by it, but I think I blogged about it last year.

Comment: .. sad to say I am just happy CF *finally* got around to actually adding proper masks for things like parseDateTime().  Most times I ended up rolling my own rather than relying on CF's creative interpretation of date strings...

Comment: (Edit) @Shawn - That is definitely a wacky one. Not helped at all by the inconsistencies in the date functions.  If you find a link for the blog entry, post it. I would definitely be interested in reading it.

Comment: @Leigh  Sorry for the delay. https://codefumonkey.blogspot.com/2016/10/more-date-masking.html is the latest. https://codefumonkey.blogspot.com/2016/02/date-masking-inconsistency.html is the original. It all makes my head hurt. :-/

Comment: @Shawn - Wow... that made me laugh (in sympathy). I agree about *not* silently swallowing date issues. Very frustrating. Better to have a "strict" setting to control the outcome, like in java? If `true` throw an error, otherwise - best guess/roll the dice.