# Adding random time to DateTime value

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11, coldfusion-2016

I would like to add a random time between 1-30 minutes to a date, but ColdFusion doesn't seem to like it. It adds the same amount of minutes to the `Now()` value no matter how many times I run the following code. I can't figure out why.

```
<cfset DateFuture = DateTimeFormat(DateAdd('n', RandRange(1, 30), Now()), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.l')/>  
<cfoutput>#DateFuture#</cfoutput>
```

I need the `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.l` DateTimeFormat because this what my datetime values in SQL Server look like which is where I plan to insert my future date.

If I run the above code I keep getting this output:

> **2017-11-25 22:11:24** 
>   and then suddenly it will change to **2017-11-25 21:11:16** which is taking away a whole hour when I only want to add to the time!

It makes no sense why its behaving like this. I am in the UK but am using international date format in the default format of SQL Server which is like above.

UPDATE: Its a typo mistake! The DateTimeFormat should be `yyyy-mm-dd HH:nn:ss.l`. 'nn' is minutes, not 'mm'. D'oh!

Comment: I would be tempted to use SQL Server's date and time. SQL 2016 has a much much more robust set of functions. There are udfs that get SQL 2014 to do all kinds of things.

Comment: Maybe but surely ColdFusion's functions are supposed to work as advertised?

Comment: Its a stupid typo. I used HH:mm:ss when it should have been HH:nn:ss

Comment: I know this is not a blog, but when you consider that SQL Server has all of these date functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql . A lot of these just don't have ColdFusion equivalents. Then again a typo will always mess things up too.

Comment: "I need the yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.l DateTimeFormat" No you don't. Insert the values as date objects, not strings and it won't be an issue.

Comment: You should move your answer out of the question and create an answer to accept.

Comment: Better yet, mark it as a duplicate. Hours vs months is a common date mask mistake. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737301/coldfusion-date-and-time-formatting-is-rounding-up-5-minutes

Comment: I would agree with `volume one` that CF functions should work, but I'd still agree with `James`' suggestion to use the SQL date functions, especially if it will ultimately be inserted back into the db. Also, date masking gets weird anyway. If you work with dates, I would _HIGHLY_ recommend keeping a list of your maskings handy. `mm` and `nn` are frustrating, but, I'll say again, `YYYY` and `yyyy` will drive you absolutely bonkers.

Comment: @Ageax It has to be inserted as a string if I want the full date and time. using cf_sql_date just puts in a date and cf_sql_timestamp doesn't include the milliseconds.

Comment: "cf_sql_timestamp doesn't include the milliseconds" @volumeone - Yeah it does. Which database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ColdFusion - Date and Time formatting is rounding up 5 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737301/coldfusion-date-and-time-formatting-is-rounding-up-5-minutes)

Comment: @Ageax SQL Server

Comment: @volumeone - What data type? Works fine with datetime (2018-01-09 15:13:02.463, 2018-01-09 15:13:03.617). Though old versions used to round milliseconds to 1/300th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole problem was down to a typo. It should be `HH:nn:ss`. Notice the `nn` and not `mm` for minutes.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the minutes, 1 to 30 range won't give you many values.

You'll make it somewhat more random using `seconds` [600 to 1800] or `miliseconds` [600000 to 1800000].

```
<cfset miliSeconds = RandRange(600000, 1800000) />
<cfdump var="#miliSeconds#" />

<cfset DateFuture = DateTimeFormat( DateAdd('l', miliSeconds, now()),  'yyyy-mm-dd HH:nn:ss.l')/>  
<cfdump var="#DateFuture#" />
```

---

***Run Code:***
https://trycf.com/gist/f26ff8edbe1736e453ded06d5adf5076/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: The whole problem was down to a typo. It should be HH:nn:ss. Notice the 'nn' and not 'mm' for minutes.